# The wave nature of light

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light

Light is an electromagnetic wave composed of electric and magnetic components.

I recently read that the velocity of light is in the direction $\mathbf{E}\times\mathbf{B}$ where $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are the electric and magnetic field vectors.

Now, suppose at some point in space, the electric and magnetic fields are $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$, which are both functions of time, suppose that we place a mirror there, perpendicular to the incident light, then, due to reflection from denser medium, there will be a phase difference of $\pi$ in the electric and magnetic field components of the wave.
So, the electric and magnetic fields are $-\mathbf{E}, -\mathbf{B}$ after reflection. Hence, the direction of propagation of light after reflection is the same as the direction of  $(\mathbf{-E})\times(\mathbf{-B})=\mathbf{E}\times\mathbf{B}$ which means that the light wave is still traveling in the same direction.

Where is the error in this?

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia, [Reflection Phase Change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_phase_change)

> "Phase" here is the phase of the electric field oscillations, not the
> magnetic field oscillations (while the electric field will undergo
> 180° phase change, the magnetic field will undergo 0° phase change.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose interface to be $xy$-plane then
$$\mathbf{E}_I(z,t)=E_{0I} \ e^{i(k_1z-\omega t)}\hat{x}$$
$$\mathbf{B}_I(z,t)=\frac{1}{v_1}E_{0I} \ e^{i(k_1z-\omega t)}\hat{y}$$

It gives rise to a reflected wave,
$$\mathbf{E}_R(z,t)=E_{0R} \ e^{i(-k_1z-\omega t)}\hat{x}$$
$$\mathbf{B}_R(z,t)=-\frac{1}{v_1}E_{0R} \ e^{i(-k_1z-\omega t)}\hat{y}$$
Now if $v_2<v_1$ then there will be phase difference introducing this to reflected waves
$$\mathbf{E}_R(z,t)=E_{0R} \ e^{i(-k_1z-\omega t+\pi)}\hat{x}$$
$$\mathbf{B}_R(z,t)=-\frac{1}{v_1}E_{0R} \ e^{i(-k_1z-\omega t+\pi)}\hat{y}$$

$$\mathbf{E}_R(z,t)=-E_{0R} \ e^{i(-k_1z-\omega t)}\hat{x}$$
$$\mathbf{B}_R(z,t)=\frac{1}{v_1}E_{0R} \ e^{i(-k_1z-\omega t)}\hat{y}$$

The direction of wave propagation: $-\hat{x}\times\hat{j}=-\hat{k}$

It should be.

---

Reference : Sec. 9.3.2 Electrodynamics : DJ Griffith

Comment: Also, can we explain it using the fact that magnetic field is a pseudo vector?